# Swipe release in ADB / Python

Tags: python, adb

I'm trying to automate a swipe input that goes from x1,y1 to x2,y2 quickly and then at the final position holds on to the screen for 5 seconds before releasing...

How can this be done in Python using ADB?

I tried this but it just slowly swipes for 5 seconds, instead of swiping fast to the endpoint and then HOLDS the swipe for 5 seconds...

```
device.shell('input touchscreen swipe 540 1000 540 1700 5000')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) with [CulebraTester-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) backend, you can do something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

s = []
for i in range(1000, 1700, 100):
    s.append((540, i))
s.extend([(540, 1700)] * 250)


helper = ViewClient.view_client_helper()

# Performs a swipe from one coordinate to another using the number of steps to determine smoothness and speed.
# Each step execution is throttled to 5ms per step.
helper.ui_device.swipe(segments=s, segment_steps=2)
```

which I guess does what you want. Perhaps you need to tweak some of the parameters though.

Notice that as all the steps are timed equally you have to add the last point multiple times to the segment list, and this is not exactly adb.

It is based on the example: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/swipe ([keep-swipe.gif](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/keep-swipe.gif)).

Answer (score 0):

try use `motionevent` instead of `swipe`:

```
def motionevent(action, x, y):
    device.shell(f"input motionevent {action} {x} {y}") 
    
def unlock_phone():
    motionevent("DOWN", x1, y1)
    motionevent("MOVE", x, y)   # some point between start -> end, as you wish
    motionevent("MOVE", x, y)   # some point between start -> end, as you wish
    motionevent("MOVE", x2, y2)
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        motionevent("MOVE", x2, y2) # hold here
    motionevent("UP", x2, y2)   # release
```